# Python process on remote server need to ssh to other and continue running

Tags: python

Is it possible to solve that a running Python process which is running on a remote server, ssh to other and then continue running?

```
run in 192.168.100.1
|
ssh to there 192.168.100.2
|
run continuously on 192.168.100.2 and do other functions from py
```

I tried with subprocess call but when the script call ssh command and connect to the other, it stops and wait there.

Comment: try `screen` on unix based systems maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You need use RPC to call python function on remote server.

There are many libs around. Let's take [RPyC](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lib  for example:

```
>>> import rpyc
>>> c = rpyc.classic.connect("localhost")
>>> c.execute("print 'hi there'")   # this will print on the host
>>> import sys
>>> c.modules.sys.stdout = sys.stdout
>>> c.execute("print 'hi here'")   # now this will be redirected here
hi here
```

Please note that you need to install RPyC server on your remote host and deploy your python modules there as well.

Please read [tutorials](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tut1.html#tut1) to learn how to start RPyC server and deploy your code on remote machine

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. When I run ssh hostname I need to run other functions from my py, not usual commands.

Comment: @tmsblgh Do you mean you need to execute python functions on remote host?

Comment: Yes, I need to execute functions.

Comment: In any case, before executing functions you have to upload your code to remote server firstly.